# Deactivate AudioSession in AudioKit

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudiosession, audiokit

I'm using AudioKit, and trying to set audio session inactive, when I don't need it. So, I wrote some simple code to understand mechanism of this process, and faced one unexpectable trouble. With attempts of deactivating session, I'm getting error:

```
[avas] AVAudioSession.mm:1079:-[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.
ViewController.swift:deactivateAudioSession():73:Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560030580 "(null)"
```

This is my sample code:

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var reverb: AKReverb?
    var delay: AKDelay?
    var chorus: AKChorus?
    var mic: AKMicrophone!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillResignActive),
                                               name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification,
                                               object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive),
                                               name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
                                               object: nil)

        super.viewDidLoad()
        AKSettings.useBluetooth = true
        guard let mic = AKMicrophone() else { return }
        self.mic = mic
        chorus = AKChorus(mic)
        chorus?.depth = 1
        chorus?.frequency = 44000
        let delay = AKDelay(chorus)
        delay.feedback = 0.2
        reverb = AKReverb(delay)
        let mix = AKMixer(reverb)
        AudioKit.output = mix
    }

    @IBAction func launchEngine() {
        do {
            try AudioKit.start()
        } catch {
            AKLog(error)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func deactivateAudioSession() {
//        mic.stop()
//        reverb?.stop()
//        delay?.stop()
//        chorus?.stop()
        do {
            try AKSettings.session.setActive(false)
        } catch {
            AKLog(error)
        }
    }

    @objc func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        launchEngine()
    }

    @objc func applicationWillResignActive() {
        deactivateAudioSession()
    }
```

}

As you can see, basically, I wanted to handle app state changing, but this error happens even if I call `deactivateAudioSession()` method using UI. I've tried to `stop()` all node objects (commented code) before deactivation, but error stays. What I'm doing wrong?